# How to use Poetry to install MongoDB database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-poetry

I am writing my first python script which would use the pymongo library to persist data into a MongoDB NOSQL database. This script is running within a Poetry managed virtual environment and therefore pyproject.toml declares the following dependencies:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
sparqlwrapper = "^2.0.0"
rdflib = "^6.2.0"
pandas = "^1.5.3"
requests = "^2.28.2"
geocoder = "^1.38.1"
geonames-rdf = "^0.2.3"
lxml = "^4.9.2"
pytz = "^2022.7.1"
pymongo = "^4.3.3"
```

Is it possible to use Poetry to also ensure the MongoDB server itself is installed as well? Of course I could install MongoDB on my Mac via homebrew manually. Best practice?

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: I am afraid you're right :) Just asking hoping there's a way that doesn't cross our minds. Thank you !!!

Comment: I did a [quick search on *PyPI*](https://pypi.org/search/?q=mongo+server), but could not find it. It could have been, because in principle I guess that it should be possible to package a DB server in a *pip*-installable package, although a bit surprising. -- If you used `sqlite`, then it would be included in Python's standard library. But of course it is a very different thing (not even a server).

Comment: Depending on your exact use case, there are things that might come close enough: https://pypi.org/project/montydb/ -- https://pypi.org/project/pymongo-inmemory/ -- https://pypi.org/project/mongobox/ -- https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock-resources/ --

Comment: Thanks a lot will go through these and see how they're usable.